# rxdart is not installing in my PC due to some issue in dart SDK version

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, rxdart

I'm trying to install rxdart by copying it from https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/versions/0.7.1#-installing-tab- , but its showing some error.

The current Dart SDK version is 2.3.0-dev.0.5.flutter-a1668566e5.

Because flutter_course depends on rxdart >=0.1.0+1 <0.16.0 which requires SDK version >1.12.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1

I tried using flutter upgrade.
But that doesn't change anything.

My pubsec.yaml file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+1
  rxdart: ^0.7.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: can't you use latest version of rxdart?

Comment: what is `flutter_course`? and why do you want 2 yours old version of rxdart (0.7.1)?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/versions/0.7.1#-installing-tab- This link is showing the same version, isn't it the latest one?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/versions/0.7.1#-versions-tab-

Comment: I think you are saying flutter_course is a package. And that package uses rxdart `>=0.1.0+1 <0.16.0` so you cannot have greater than that, You have three options: if there is a update for flutter_course use upgrade it or remove it or you have to rely on that dart version

Comment: I upgraded my rxdart version from 0.7.1 to 0.22.0 and it worked. Thanks a lot.